# setting stash snippet as author_id does not parse

Tags: stash, entry, author

I try to store member_id/author_id for session during visit of other users. Goal: show content of a certain user without showing the id in a URL.

My **testing** template has the author_id in segment_2.
I can get this segment_2 with stash, this outputs in the template allright.
Like this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="sn_author" scope="user" save="yes" type="snippet"}{segment_2}{/exp:stash:set}


{if sn_author == segment_2}success{/if}
```

But I cannot make this work inside a regular EE entrees tag.

The EE tag outputs correct when hardcoding the desired author_id.
But when I use stash get, it does not work.
I understand this is a parsing order.
I tried process="end" no luck.

My EE entrees tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" dynamic="off" author_id="{exp:stash:sn_author process="end"}"}{member_first_name} {member_last_name} {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I am rather new to stash, cannot get around this, and do hope for an answer here, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a tag as a parameter (any tag, not just Stash) you need to add `parse="inward"` to the parent tag to tell EE to parse the parameters.

```
{exp:stash:set name="sn_author" scope="user" save="yes"}{segment_2}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" dynamic="no" author_id="{exp:stash:sn_author}" parse="inward"}
   {member_first_name} {member_last_name} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Ehm, Mark? I accepted your answer, but I am afraid I still have problems with it, I am sorry...... The tag returns all the entrees, so author_id is not parsed inside the EE tag at all It is given allright by stash which I can see if I call it outside EE tag. Tried this on a plain template, nothing else there. Could you give me advise why this could be so?

Comment: `dynamic="no"`, not "off"

Comment: Thanks for coming back. No luck, result is still empty stash tag. How can I test my setup of stash? Maybe something wrong there? This is so difficult......

Comment: Mark, could you please look one more time at my code? I am running in circles, getting nowhere. Setting this in template one: {exp:stash:set name="sn_author" scope="user" save="yes" type="snippet"}{segment_3}{/exp:stash:set} and getting in template two (=same user, same session) {exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" dynamic="no" author_id="{exp:stash:sn_author trim="yes" scope="user" save="yes" type="snippet"}" parse="inward"} {member_first_name} {member_last_name} {/exp:channel:entries} just gives all the names, not the one from the author. Thank you very very much....

Comment: You set the variable to `type="snippet"` but were trying to access it as one would a native variable. https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Terminology#type

I have edited my answer above to show you how to set the variable. Btw, I don't get notifications on these things so please contact me direct to bring to my attention @croxton on twitter.